# Why does create table execute in SQL Server with having specified the database with a USE db?

Tags: sql-server

A new query was created from the Server using SQL Server Management Studio and the following was executed without getting an error:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name
(
    Column_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Column_etc VARCHAR(255),
    Column_etc2 VARCHAR(255),
    Column_etc3 VARCHAR(255),
    Column_etc4 VARCHAR(255) 
);
```

1. Why would the execution not return an error if no database had been chosen?
2. If the `CREATE TABLE` indeed executed, where would this table show up?
3. After realizing that no Database had been specified for `USE`, I executed `USE db_name` and then re-executed the `CREATE TABLE` as before, and that too worked with receiving and error; what's the SQL server logic of this phenomena?

Comment: Please find the suggestions below,

1) The table would be created in the db which is currently active.

Comment: What do *you* think the answers are, and then we can tell you if you're right or wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the scenario in 3 is a "phenomena" at all; it's expected behaviour.

Comment: copy this statement `select 'currently database ' +  db_name() + ' is your active database'` in your SSMS and that will give you a hint

Comment: Srinivasan Rajasekaran Which db is active if i had chosen a generic New Query? there was no db chosen, and i checked all the db's and none of the refelcted a created table.

Comment: if you have no database choosen, then you will be in your default database. Check the command in my prior comment

Comment: @Sir_Arch_Ing You can't open a connection without making a connection to a database. System Databases (like `master`) are databases too and you can create objects in those. I bet you created your object there.

Comment: GuidoG Thank you! Indeed, I found a replica of the Created table in the Master db. The Master db seems to be the default db.

Comment: You can find the default database of a login through `sys.server_principals`. If no default database is explicitly set on creation, it will default to `master`. (Unfortunately -- if it defaulted to `tempdb` there'd be less garbage to clean up.)

Comment: Answer: Default db = Master in SSMS, and that is where the first execution  of CREATE TABLE will end up, when no db is specified. 

Thank you everyone!

Comment: *I think you'll find it was me who said you'll find it in `master`, not GuidoG...*

Comment: *"Default db = Master in SSMS"* That isn't true. A Login has a default Database; not an application. Every login can have a different default database, and where the table (in this example) is created totally depends on the Login (not the application). Plus you can specify a database in your connection too, which would ignore the Login's default database.

Comment: @Larnu yes I never said that, I only showed him a way to see what database he is currently connected to, which was `master` in this case

Comment: Thank you Larnu, I was already was working on GuioG's comment before I saw your response. 

Also based on your last statement ill modify my answer. 

Thank you Larnu

Comment: As already stated, you ARE IN a database, but probably "master".  You have to be careful not to touch master db.

Comment: granadaCoder I am using Sandbox, but its good to know that in general I should be careful with "Master". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A CREATE TABLE query will execute into the default db if no specific db is chosen! That is why no error was received.

What the default db will be depends on the login, and therefore can vary from user to user. (credit Larnu)

Additionally a user can specify which db to use within the connection and thereby sidestep starting with the default db entirely. (credit Larnu)

The Default db in SSMS in my case was called 'Master', and that is where the first execution of CREATE TABLE ended up. (credit GuidoG)

The subsequent CREATE TABLE which was executed after a specific db was chosen also executed, with the same table being created with this second db.